# Use regex/php to read text inside quotations

Tags: php, regex

I have a text title that reads

```
This User "The Title Of The Post"
```

I want to grab just whats INSIDE of the quotation marks, and store it in a variable. How would i do this with regex and php?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.php.net/preg_match

```
<?php
$x = 'This User "The Title Of The Post"';

preg_match('/".*?"/', $x, $matches);

print_r($matches);

/*
  Output:
  Array
  (
      [0] => "The Title Of The Post"
  )

*/
?>
```

Comment: The same that I had come up with. :-)

Comment: The poster asked for "just whats INSIDE of the quotation marks" and the accepted solution includes quotation marks. My solution excludes quotation marks as the poster requested.

Comment: So either the question or the answer should change for archival purposes.  Changing the pattern to /"(.*?)"/ has the desired output in $matches[1].  Changing the function call to use preg_match_all (per jakemcgraw) would hold the desired output in $matches[1][0] (and subsequent unquoted matches in $matches[1][1..n]).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = 'This User "The Title Of The Post"';

preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'This user "The Title Of The Post"';

$its_a_match = preg_match('/"(.+?)"/', $string, $matches);
$whats_inside_the_quotes = $matches[1];
```

`$its_a_match` will be `1` if it made a successful match, otherwise `0`. `$whats_inside_the_quotes` will contain the string matched in the set of parentheses in the regex.

In case it's a bit unclear (it is), [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match) actually gives a value to `$matches` (the third argument).

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'This User "The Title Of The Post"';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^[^"]*"([^"]*)"$/', $str, $matches);
$title = $matches[1];
echo $title; // prints The Title Of The Post
```

Comment: @opello, @Patrick - could anyone of you please explain this answer a little bit... I am still new to regex. I want to do a similar task - "read the number right after `site_ids==` from  `site_ids==34||sales_region==45`" (i.e. regex should return 34). I tried with `preg_match('/^[^site_ids==]*||([^||]*)"$/', $str, $matches);` after `$str = 'site_ids==34||sales_region==45';` and not getting result. I am not sure if `|` needs escaping. The delimiter in the question is a double quote (`"`) whereas in my case they are `site_ids==` and `||`. What would be correct regex for me? Thanks.